# How do I pass in multiple parameters to a controller?

Tags: c#, kendo-ui

I am creating a simple search feature in my application and I want to use KendoUI MultiSelect.  I need to pass the parameters into the controller but it will only pass the first one you select not them all.  How can I pass multiple parameters into my controller? or is my approach incorrect for this type of thing?

Here is my code.

The view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{       
    @(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()
    .Name("vessel_type")            
    .Placeholder("-- Type --")
    .AutoBind(false)            
    .BindTo(new List<string>() {
            "AHTS",
            "PSV",
            "Tug"
          }))

    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
}
```

My Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(string vessel_type)
    {
        var thevessels = from o in db.tbl_vessels
                         select o;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(vessel_type))
        {
            thevessels = thevessels.Where(x =>
                x.vessel_type.Contains(vessel_type));
        }

        return View(thecvessels);            

    }
```

As you can see I am accepting the string from vessel_type but I need it to take as many as the user chooses as there can be more than one.  Any ideas?

Many thanks

Comment: Have you thought about passing an array/array of arguments and parsing the values out of the array depending on its length? That way you will only be passing one item around at least

Comment: Firstly, your form method defaults to `POST`, so your controller Action will need the `[HttpPost]` attribute if you want it to be - otherwise you will need to change your `FormAction` to `GET`. Secondly, since you're creating a `List<string>` to bind to in the view, why not accept `List<string>` in the controller parameters? The `DefaultModelBinder` should be able to pick this up, and then do something with the data passed to it? Are you using a strongly-typed view?

Answer (score 0):

Though it may not be the cleanest solution you could use $('#vessel_type').data('kendoMultiSelect').value() then concat the results into a string and ajax them down to your controller. Have you tried using string[] vessel_type yet?